# Manage the duration of the life cycle of an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

could you  suggest me how can I make my app does not go on pause?
Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do? Why can't the app pause?

Comment: I'm trying to make a sudoku but the problem That I can not figure out how to solve Is that while i try to complete the sudoku the screen goes Completely black, forcing me to have to turn on the screen and do the release to return at play

Comment: Have a look at the logs in your logcat. There may be some clues there as to what is going on. If you are just trying to prevent the screen getting dim while the user is using your game you can get a wakelock to keep the screen on. However, be aware that this uses a lot of battery and your users will get mad at you and uninstall your game and give you bad reviews. If the user is actively touching the screen while playing, it shouldn't go dim.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you essentially have no control over the state of your main activity.  `onPause()` will get called anytime you application loses the foreground.  You can look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to get a general idea of how life cycles work.  You can use a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to keep executing tasks even while your application is in the background.  It would also be a good idea to save state anytime `onPause()` is called. That way the user can resume your application smoothly, even if it is eventually killed by the os.